# Local App Engine MVM Java8/Jetty 9 Compat RCP Failure for API call: datastore_v3 Get

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsf-2.2

I am trying to move the code to run under the "Java 8/Jetty 9 Compat" managed VM.  When I try to run the application locally with `mvn gcloud:run`, I see the following error:

```
[INFO] Mar 19, 2016 5:18:13 AM com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SessionManager loadSession
[INFO] WARNING: Exception while loading session data
[INFO] com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreFailureException: RCP Failure for API call: datastore_v3 Get
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.constructApiException(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:246)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.runSyncCall(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:195)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.makeApiCall(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:154)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate.access$000(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:60)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate$MakeSyncCall.call(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:436)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.VmApiProxyDelegate$MakeSyncCall.call(VmApiProxyDelegate.java:412)
[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[INFO]  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And once the session data cannot be loaded, my JSF application fails with a `javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException`

```
[INFO] Mar 19, 2016 5:18:13 AM com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl handlePartialResponseError
[INFO] SEVERE: javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: viewId:/loginProblem.jsf - View /loginProblem.jsf could not be restored.
[INFO]  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.execute(RestoreViewPhase.java:212)
[INFO]  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
[INFO]  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RestoreViewPhase.doPhase(RestoreViewPhase.java:123)
[INFO]  at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
[INFO]  at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:595)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.jetty9.VmRuntimeWebAppContext.doScope(VmRuntimeWebAppContext.java:269)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:191)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:72)
[INFO]  at com.wildstartech.servicedesk.servlet.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:57)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
[INFO]  at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.jetty9.VmRuntimeWebAppContext.doScope(VmRuntimeWebAppContext.java:299)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
[INFO]  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
[INFO]  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Per the "Local Testing" section of the "[The Java 8 / Jetty 9.3 Compat Runtime](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/java/dev-jetty9-and-apis)":

> When you are testing in your local environment, not all Google Cloud Services are emulated. There is an emulator for Cloud Datastore, use the `gcloud` command to start it before you run your app:

`gcloud beta emulators datastore start`

Even with the emulator running, we are still seeing the "RCP Failure for API call: datastore_v3 Get" error message.

According to the JavaDoc for the "[DatastoreFailureException]" [2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreFailureException) class

> DatastoreFailureException is thrown when any unknown error occurs while communicating with the data store. Clients should not attempt to retry after receiving this exception.

This error is happening with the `loadSession` method of the `com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty9.SessionManager`.

Comment: Using the Cloud SDK v102.0.0 does NOT fix the problem.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? I get the same problems but never consistently. Very odd

Comment: I never got this resolved and ended up moving back to the compatible environment because I was slipping behind on some deliverables.

Comment: Same as me. It's annoying as I want to use Java 8 Streams in my server code